# Read content of zip file without extracting that

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

is it possible to perfom some tasks on files in .zip file without really extracting it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The [`zipfileset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) is a resource collection which represents the files within a zipfile.

So any Ant task which accept a resource collection as input (for instance the copy task) can deal with your files within the zip file.